# How can I render entries from one fields with different widget depending a column value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've a model 'Formation' with tree fields:

1. `abbr` a *CharField* ;
2. `is_supplementary` a *BooleanField* ;
3. `description` a *TextField*.

### Models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User attach to a working site/location"""
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site')
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, null=True)
    formations = models.ManyToManyField('Formation')
    objects = UserManager()

class Formation(models.Model):
    """Available formations."""
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=8, help_text=_('Abbréviation'))
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_supplementary = models.BooleanField(help_text=_('Formations complémentaires'))
```

### Forms.py

The `Formation` model is used as followed (it's part of a m2m relation)

```python
class InternalActorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # group = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            'phone',
            'formations'
        )
        widgets = {
            'password': PasswordInput(),
            'formations': CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }
```

### Question

Currently all entries are rendered with a single widget `CheckboxSelectMultiple()`.

How can I render entries from one fields with different widget depending a column value?

- entries with `is_supplementary=True` as a group of check-boxes ;
- while rendering the one with `is_supplementary=False` as a `select` (*i.e.* `SelectMultiple()`).

**Update:** All entries belong to the **same queryset**, so the different should happen inside a single form instance.

Updates

- add `User` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to overwrite `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`. I'll show you an example where depending on the data I use some widget or omit them:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):       
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # I send this user where I initialize the form
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)  
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Now you can define the widgets to use depending on your conditions
        if self.user:  # If I receive the user I select this widget
            self.fields['profile_role'] = forms.CharField(max_length=25, widget=forms.Select(choices=self.user.profile.getUserRoles()))
        # And I define here other widgets
        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _(u'Nombre de Usuario')})
        self.fields['first_name'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _(u'Nombre')})
        self.fields['last_name'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _(u'Apellidos')})
        self.fields['email'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _(u'E-mail')})
```

This is my example, I think it would help you to understand how to achieve what you need. In the form declaration in my view I send the user like this:

```
form = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

You can send the variables you need and receive in the  `__init__` form and use one widget or other depending on your needs.

You need to pass to the form your `formation` object where you store `is_supplementary`, and then in the `__init__` you could do something like:

```
if your_object.is_supplementary:
    self.fields['YOUR_FIELD'].widget = forms.YOUR_DESIRED_WIDGET
else:
    self.fields['YOUR_FIELD'].widget = forms.YOUR_OTHER_DESIRED_WIDGET
```

Comment: he field in question is a `M2M` from `User` (I updated my question description) to `Formation`

Comment: Wich is the condition to add one widget or another ?

Comment: I got this error _'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'is_supplementary'_

Comment: Can you show me the code you're using ? Edit your post and add some info